# PHPMailer profile image

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

In Gmail every user has a profile image, that will send with the mail. Is there a possibility that PHPMailer can do that instead of https://i.stack.imgur.com/mep7m.png?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The profile image shown by Gmail is not controllable by the script. When you send an email through PHPMailer, Gmail will check if that receiving email address has a Google profile, if it does, it will show the image of the Google profile and if not it will show a placeholder image there.